# I have used @AfterClass and After TearDown test closed but next class page doesn't take initiate to run

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

I want to @AfterClass teardown and the next class should initiate/be configured again. For example: Class1 closed Class 2 should run But I am not sure what is wrong with my code

```
XML Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
    
    <classes>
      <class name="com.example.chat_pom.ProfileEditTest"/>
      <class name="com.example.chat_pom.ProfileImageTest"/>
      <class name="com.example.chat_pom.FeedTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Class 1

```
public class ProfileImageTest extends TestBase  {

    ProfilePage profilePage;

    public ProfileImageTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        initialization();
        profilePage = new ProfilePage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void UserProfileImageTest() {

        profilePage.setUploadProfilePhoto();
   
        Assert.assertTrue(profilePage.ValidateThumbnail());
    }

    @AfterClass(enabled = true)
    public void teardown() {

        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to move next class after teardown First Class

Class 2

```
public class FeedTest extends TestBase {
    ExploreFeed exploreFeed;

    public FeedTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        initialization();
        exploreFeed = new ExploreFeed();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void ExploreBtn() {
     exploreFeed.ValidateExploreBtn();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void FeedClickTest() {
        exploreFeed.FeedClickBtn();
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void GalleryImageTest() throws InterruptedException {
    exploreFeed.GalleryBtnClick();
    exploreFeed.GalleryImageEditor();

    }

    @AfterClass(enabled = false)
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

But when I run this code class 1 teardown but Class 2 didn't start

Comment: Could you please post your code and not screenshots?

Comment: I did, can you please help me

Comment: @demonplus can you please help

Answer (score 0):

@BeforeClass and @AfterClass just define functions that should be run before and after any @Test cases in that class. It would be down to how you run your code in the IDE or environment that you are using, i.e. run a single class or a suite of classes.

Try these:

@BeforeClass and @AfterClass: https://www.guru99.com/junit-test-framework.html

Test Suite: https://www.guru99.com/create-junit-test-suite.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please give example